# looking for SharePoint REST API end point to get list view items

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

we are trying to get SP list view items, means whatever the fields that are enabled in that specific view, those fields(columns) and items.
so what SP REST API end point is helpful
ex:...

to get SP lists: `_api/web/lists`

to get SP list view: `_api/web/getlistbytitle('sampleList')/views`

etc... we need SP list view items
Please assist me on how to get list view items.

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the [ViewQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj247163(v=office.15)) for the view and use it to execute a [CAML query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245102(v=office.15)) on the list.

This post on SharePoint StackExchange has details: [How to get all items in a view using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135936/how-to-get-all-items-in-a-view-using-rest-api).

Here's the relevant code snippet from that post:

```
function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, queryText) 
{
    var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + queryText + '</Query></View>';
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
    var queryPayload = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml  
               }
    };
    return executeJson(url,"POST",null,queryPayload);
}


function getListViewItems(webUrl,listTitle,viewTitle)
{
     var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/Views/getbytitle('" + viewTitle + "')/ViewQuery";
     return executeJson(url).then(
         function(data){         
             var viewQuery = data.d.ViewQuery;
             return getListItems(webUrl,listTitle,viewQuery); 
         });
}
```